# using a do while how can i populate the blanks which is equal to a specific cell value from a pivot table?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sheets one is for a output sheet then the other is for the raw sheet.  Now on the output sheet there is a column a and b. There is some data in column b which is blank and i want to populate those blanks using the raw sheet. Then put it in the output sheet.

I tried to use a loop that is finding a blank then replacing it a specific value.

Here is the code that i tried so far. im searching for a blank data and replace it with the "fill" value:

```
Sub LoopSample()

 i = 2

Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output").Range("A" & i).Value <> ""

    If Len(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output").Range("B" & i).Value) = 0 Then

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output").Range("B" & i).Value = "fill"

   End If

     i = i + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Here is the sheets that i am using:

[image: Output]

[image: raw]

Comment: Hi @Damian, how did you extract the picture from the link? thats what i want to do earlier :D

Comment: I think you have not enough reputation to do so, so I edited it :)

Comment: In your example you have 4 rows with fill which belong to Administration, but in administration you have 2 options, how do you know which one you need in each case coder?

Comment: @Damian oh i see thank you for that one :)

Comment: @Damian for administration they dont have hierarchy. its just that if it will be equal to administration you just need to fill the blanks. wait i will update the raw sheet

Comment: Coder, still.. should the macro fill the blank cell for administration with Others? With Communications & Development Office? With  Finance? With HR? If there are multiple choice how does the macro know which one to use?

Comment: @Damian yes there are no requirements about which one should put first. When it is equal to a blank then the column a is equal to administration it will just get any child on the administration then will put it on the blank.

Comment: A simple macro would always put the same value... It would take a little bit more to get a random one and taking account the ones already filled. Why would you pick random childs?

Comment: oh sorry i think was wrong about what i said.. as per the requirement they just want to have is to fill the blanks with the childs which will show all under the parents so lets say if we put a hr in one of the blanks then next we will put a finance on the 2nd blank and then so on and so forth. as long as it is equal to the parent. but they said that there no hierarchy on the childs which should be first to put on the blanks.